# Confusion in a number theory topic

Tags: number-theory

I noticed a recurring pattern in $2^x \mod 100$.
The terms go like this :

$ 1 \  2  \ 4 \  8  \ 16  \ 32  ..   \ 88  \ 76  \ 52  |  \ 4  \ 8  \ 16  \ 32  ..  \ 88  \ 76  \ 52  |  \ 4  \ 8  \ 16  \ 32 $ and so on

The bars are where pattern repeats. Why is it that $2^x \mod 100$ recurs in every 22 terms. And why is the same true for other bases other than $ 2 $ ?

Comment: That' because you have only finitely many values, namely $0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 99$. This means that if you go on forever it must repeat at some point. In other words, to have a non-repeating pattern, you would need infinitely many different numbers mod 100, while you have only finitely many.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n  This a possibly interesting link for you -- it requires some group theory knowledge.

Comment: Note that this is very similar to the reason why the decimal representation of a rational number always has to repeat.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $2^{20}\equiv1\bmod25$, so $2^{x+20}\equiv2^x\bmod25$, and for $x\ge2,$ $2^x\equiv0\bmod4$; thus for $x\ge2, 2^{x+20}\equiv2^x\bmod100$

Comment: Note it repeats ever $20$ terms, not $22$.  The first two terms $01, 02$ never occur again.

Comment: Note.  Because $2$ and $100$ are *not* relatively prime you never get "back" to $1$. And because $2^2|100$ we never get back to $2$ and all the terms that repeat are multiples of $4$.  If you did something relatively prime to $100$ such as $3$ or $35$ you *will* get back to one.  Indeed the cycle for $7^x$ is short.  $1, 7, 49, 43,1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euler's theorem, (which is a result that comes from analyzing the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$), tells you that $$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$ if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

In this case
we can't use Euler's theorem directly since $\gcd(2,100)=2$. But we can express  $100=2^25^2=4*25$. So, we can apply the theorem to deduce that $2^{\varphi(25)}=1\mod 25$, i.e. $2^{20}=1\mod 25$. In particular, this tells you that $$2^{20+x}=2^{x}\mod 25$$
If $x\geq 2$, you also have 
$$2^{20+x}=2^x=0\mod 4$$
Hence, $2^{20+x}=2^x\mod 100$ for $x\geq 2$. This tells you that your pattern is repeated every 20 terms.

You can do similar things with other bases.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2^x \mod 100$ can take at most $100$ values. ($0, \ldots 99$)
Thus, there would have to be some number that gets repeated twice. (You can even put an upper bound - within the first 101 terms, it's forced that there's repetition.)

Now, if you get that $2^{x_1} \equiv 2^{x_2}\mod100$, then the terms after that are bound to repeat as well since
$$2^{x_1+1} = 2\cdot2^{x_1} \equiv 2\cdot2^{x_2} \equiv 2^{x_2+1} \mod 100.$$

In your case, you see that this happened for the first time with $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = 22$.

---

It is easy to see that there was nothing special about $2$ *or* $100$. Indeed, given any integers $a$ and $b (\neq 0)$, the pattern is bound to repeat. The thing that will change is the length of the cycle.